# is there a general formula for $\int_a^b [f'(x)]^2 dx$?

Tags: calculus, analysis

what about the general case : $\int_a^b [f'(x)]^n dx$?

We know $\int_a^b f'(x) dx=f(b)-f(a)$ by the fundamental theorem, but what if the integrand has a power of n?

Comment: Did you try integration by parts?

Comment: integration by parts would involve the second derivative which makes things worse

Comment: Forget it, there is no general formula.

Comment: Just an idea on why one might not expect a similarly "nice" formula (in particular involving $f$) in this case: Assume $f$ can be expressed in terms of elementary functions but $(f')^n$ does not admit an elementary antiderivative for some $n$. In that case having a "nice" formula dependent on $f$ only would contradict the function's property outlined above.

Comment: I know, but you didnt provide anything that you yourself had tried. @bbw